# Custom on the fly e-mail alerts

Tags: plugins

Is there a way where users can opt-in for ‘random keywords’ that match their interests?

The user can just enter any keyword they want in a search box and hit enter.

After that the user will be given the option to opt-in for that specific keyword.

After that if content is posted with keywords in the title that matches that keyword, an email will be generate and sent to that user.

It's much like the way Indeed works.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Of course it can, but that's a lot of things, can you narrow it down and break the problem apart? It's currently far too broad ( you're allowed to ask multiple questions )

Comment: I want users to subscribe via email for ANY keyword they want. 

Just type the keyword, after that a form should appear with the option for subscribing on that specific keyword.

ALL options that I found, including premium options, only allow users to subscribe on specific categories. 

What if a category is too broad? What if the needs are more specific.

See this example below:
Indeed .com / jobs?q=any+keyword&l=

You can type any keyword you want in the box, and subscribe on it. 

If there’s any relevant content posted afterwards, it sends you an email (how awesome is that btw).

Comment: I understand exactly what you want, what I'm saying is that your question is too broad, too all encompassing, too much, break it into smaller problems and ask questions for each of those or you'll either get no responses, down votes, or closed as too broad. As it is now, unless someone writes an answer for every small piece in 1 huge answer you're not going to get any. Breaking it apart means individual parts can be answered by those who know how to do them. Remember this is a Q&A site not a forum, questions must be answerable, they're not discussions